# Can't get shake events on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, shake, motion-detection

I am not being able to get shake events on iPhone.

I have followed other questions here with no result. I also tried following the GLPaint example from Apple, but it seems exactly like my source code, with a small diference. GLPaint's source code /works/, mine /doesn't/.

So, here it is what I have:

Controller.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shakeEnded) name:@"shake" object:nil];
}
```

ShakingEnabledWindow.m

```
- (void)shakeEnded {
    NSLog(@"Shaking ended.");
}

- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
        // User was shaking the device. Post a notification named "shake".
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shake" object:self];
        NSLog(@"Shaken!");
    }
}

- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
}
```

My XIB has a window, which is a ShakingEnabledWindow and an object, my Controller.

I am running out of ideas here, hope someone can give me a hand. :)

Comment: Are you trying to get this to work with a `View` or a `ViewController`?

Comment: In a window, as done here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are incorrectly checking the motion type. You need to check against `event.subtype` instead of `motion`:

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
        // Put in code here to handle shake
    }
}
```

Comment: @MegaEduX: Did you try my original code, or my revised answer?

Comment: I had tried event.subtype also. Apple's examples check against motion, that's why I used it. Tried it again anyway, no worky.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of NSNotificationCenter says:

> **addObserver:selector:name:object:**
>   *notificationSelector* Selector that
>   specifies the message the receiver
>   sends notificationObserver to notify
>   it of the notification posting. The
>   method specified by
>   notificationSelector **must have one and
>   only one argument** (an instance of
>   NSNotification).

So your shakeEnded method is wrong as it takes no parameters. It should look:

```
- (void)shakeEnded:(NSNotification*)notiication {
    NSLog(@"Shaking ended.");
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shakeEnded:) name:@"shake" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidAppear`, become the first responder:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And make sure you can be first responder:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Then you can implement the motion detection.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventTypeMotion){
        //there was motion
    }
}
```

Comment: event.subtype and motion are the same in my testing.